# Byte to value error

Tags: c#, random, biginteger, bigdecimal

So in c#, I have needed a random below given number generator and I found one on [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357760/how-can-i-generate-a-random-biginteger-within-a-certain-range). But near the end, it converts the byte array into a BigInteger. I tried doing the same, though I am using the Deveel-Math lib as it allows me to us BigDeciamals. But I have tried to the array change into a value, and that into a String but I keep getting a "Could not find any recognizable digits." error and as of now I am stumped.

```
public static BigInteger RandomIntegerBelow1(BigInteger N)
    {
        byte[] bytes = N.ToByteArray();
        BigInteger R;
        Random random = new Random();

        do
        {
            random.NextBytes(bytes);
            bytes[bytes.Length - 1] &= (byte)0x7F; //force sign bit to positive

            R = BigInteger.Parse(BytesToStringConverted(bytes)) ;
           //the Param needs a String value, exp: BigInteger.Parse("100")
        } while (R >= N);

        return R;
    }
    static string BytesToStringConverted(byte[] bytes)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
```

[Deveel-Math](https://github.com/deveel/deveel-math)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Wrong string conversion

You are converting your byte array to a string of characters based on UTF encoding.  I'm pretty sure this is not what you want.

If you want to convert a byte array to a string that contains a number expressed in decimal, try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166757/conversion-of-byte-array-containing-hex-values-to-decimal-values) using [BitConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    Array.Reverse(array); //need the bytes in the reverse order
int value = BitConverter.ToInt32(array, 0);
```

### This is way easier

On the other hand, I notice that [Deveel-Math's BigInteger](https://github.com/deveel/deveel-math/blob/master/src/Deveel.Math/Deveel.Math/BigInteger.cs) has a constructor that takes a byte array as input (see line 226).  So you should be able to greatly simplify your code by doing this:

```
R = new Deveel.Math.BigInteger(1, bytes) ;
```

However, since Deveel.Math appears to be [BigEndian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), you may need to reverse the array first:

```
System.Array.Reverse(bytes);
R = new Deveel.Math.BigInteger(1, bytes);
```

Comment: No I'm not using the built in Math class I'm using an open source math lib called Deveel-Math. In addition I'm still lost on how to use the first method of conversion. where do I implement it?

Comment: Modified to accomodate Deveel-Math's class.

Comment: I get these options only though: https://gyazo.com/194f60bae0b9a56ad44b0b8e0ad00f96

Comment: Don't use the static `Parse` method.  Type  `new BigInteger(` and see what comes up.